# Laplacian Graph Embeddings with Weighted Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-laplacian

In ["A Simple Baseline Algorithm for Graph Classification"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.09155.pdf) it says your graph $G$ must be "undirected and unweighted". Why must it be unweighted? Looking through the equations it is not obvious why this must be the case. Is there a workaround to allow me to use weighted adjacency matrices?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit open-ended. The authors may only deal with unweighted graphs for simplicity. In an unweighted graph, the *unweighted* adjacency matrix $A$ is equal to the *weighted* adjacency matrix $W$. This allows the authors to define the *symmetric normalized Laplacian matrix*:

$$L=I-D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}.$$
where $L$ denotes the Laplacian matrix, $D$ the degree matrix, and $A$ the adjacency matrix.

Using the symmetric normalized Laplacian matrix has many advantages; see [https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/research/cb/ch1.pdf](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Efan/research/cb/ch1.pdf).

You can still use the symmetric normalized Laplacian for a weighted graph, but the eigenvalue theorems cited in the paper you linked may no longer apply.

Comment: So, I could use my symmetric weighted adjacency matrices, but there's no guarantee that it will work as intended? I'll run some tests and see. Is there a form of whole-graph embedding you know of that is intended for weighted matrices?

Comment: @Andrew As an example, I'll quote from the paper you linked: "The eigenvalues of the normalized Laplacian matrix lie between 0 and 2. Such a property is very convenient for the downstream use of a standard classifier without heavy rescaling or preprocessing." If you were to instead use an unnormalized Laplacian, the eigenvalues would lie in the interval [0,2d], where d denotes the maximal degree of the corresponding graph. So the main change if you use a weighted adjacency matrix (and thus an unnormalized L) is that the Laplacian eigenvalues will be scaled by some factor. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure if I know of any such whole-graph embedding. Tangentially, a good general source for Laplacian embeddings is this textbook http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/sagt/sagt.pdf